# Adding values to array in recursive method

Tags: ruby, arrays, recursion

Method: get_users_in_groups(groupname)
Purpose: Gets all members from group and any nested groups' members.

English translation of method:

```
get group information
if group has members, 
    add members to users[]
end
If group has nested_groups,
    for nested_group in nested_groups
        get nested_groupname
        get_users_in_groups(nested_groupname)
    end
end
```

Currently I pass the users array in the method attributes. However, this doesn't seem like the proper way to access an array in a recursive method.

What is the best way to add members to the users array through my recursive method?

I think I might have found a solution.

```
users = []
get group information
if group has members, 
   users.concat( members[] )
end
If group has nested_groups,
    for nested_group in nested_groups
        get nested_groupname
        users.concat( get_users_in_groups(nested_groupname) )
    end
end
users.uniq
```

Is this the best way to do this?

Sorry about that I meant to include one!

isc-staff
nested-groups: isc-admins, isc-teachers, isc-paras
members: none

isc-admins
nested-groups: none
members: adminone, admintwo

isc-teachers
nested-groups: sped-teachers
members: teacherone, teachertwo

isc-paras
nested-groups: none
members: paraone, paratwo

sped-teachers
nested-groups: none
members: spedteacherone, spedteachertwo

So my method looks up isc-staff, sees that it has isc-admins, isc-teachers, and isc-paras but no members, it needs to run itself on isc-admins, isc-teachers, and isc-paras.
When it runs on isc-admins it should add the members to users[]
When it runs on isc-teachers it should add the members to users[] and run itself through sped-teachers

This information isn't stored in an array, it has to be pulled from LDAP.

Is that enough information?

The structure would look something similar to

```
{
 group_name: 'isc-staff',
 nested_groups: [
                 {
                  group_name: 'isc-admins',
                  members: ['adminone', 'admintwo']
                 },
                 {
                  group_name: 'isc-teachers',
                  members: ['teacherone', 'teachertwo'],
                  nested_groups: [
                                  {
                                   group_name: 'sped-teachers',
                                   members: ['spedteacherone']
                                  }
                                 ]
                 },
                 {
                  group_name: 'isc-paras',
                  members: ['paraone', 'paratwo']
                 }
 ]
}
```

Result should be:

```
['adminone','admintwo','teacherone','teachertwo','spedteacherone','paraone','paratwo']
```

Comment: Philip, an example here would be worth 1k words.  Perhaps give an array with two levels of nesting (`[[[]]])`, together with the desired result (array).

Comment: Added two examples, the first in paragraph form describes how it actually is (where I have to get data, read it, and then get more data) the second put it in hash/array form.

Comment: Good example.  It makes your question perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is quite general.  Your structure can be an array or hash, recursively containing arrays, hashes and literals to any depth.  I have assumed the values you want are strings within arrays, and that all arrays contain no strings or only strings (though those containing no strings may contain nested arrays of strings, which will be found).

**Code**

```
def getem(e,a=[])
  case e
  when Array
    case e.first
    when String
      e.each { |f| a << f }
    else
      e.each do |f|
        case f
        when Array, Hash
          getem(f,a)
        end
      end
    end
  when Hash
    e.each { |_,v| getem(v,a) }
  end
  a
end
```

**Example**

```
h = {
 group_name: 'isc-staff',
 nested_groups:
   [
     {
        group_name: 'isc-admins',
        members: ['adminone', 'admintwo']
     },
     {
        group_name: 'isc-teachers',
        members: ['teacherone', 'teachertwo'],
        nested_groups:
          [{
              group_name: 'sped-teachers',
              members: ['spedteacherone']
          }]
     },
     {
        group_name: 'isc-paras',
        members: ['paraone', 'paratwo']
     }
   ]
}

getem(h)
  #=> ["adminone", "admintwo", "teacherone", "teachertwo",
  #   "spedteacherone", "paraone", "paratwo"]
```

(Notice that you made a couple of small mistakes in your example hash.)

**Explanation**

- `getem` is called when `e` is an array or a hash.  The return value is the array `a`, which defaults to an empty array when `getem` is first called.
- we use a `case` statement to test for an object's class.  This works because case uses [Object#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D), rather than `==`, for determining `true` or `false`.
- if the first argument of `getem` is an array, we see if the first element is a string. If it is, we assume all elements are strings, and add them to the array `a`.  Otherwise, we recursively call `getem` for each element that is an array or a hash.
- if the first argument of `getem` is a hash, we recursively call `getem` for each value that is an array or a hash.  (Since we do not use the hash keys within the block, we can write `|_v|` rather than `|k,v|`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data structure is a hash with symbol keys, a simple recursive function does the trick:

```
def all_group_members group
  members = []
  members.concat group[:members] if group[:members]
  if group[:nested_groups]
    group[:nested_groups].each { |g| members.concat all_group_members(g) }
  end
  members
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've learned about recursive queries over the past few days, I came up with this method. Does this work?

```
def self.get_users_in_group(groupname)
            users = []
            if exists?(groupname)
                params = [
                            "GroupMembership",
                            "NestedGroups"
                        ]
                DSQuery.generate_dscl("read","/Groups/#{groupname}",params)
                output = DSQuery.run
                # Add members of group to users array.
                if output.has_key?('dsAttrTypeStandard:GroupMembership')
                    users.concat(output['dsAttrTypeStandard:GroupMembership'])
                end
                # if group contains nested groups,
                # get_users_in_group for each nested group and add to users array.
                if output.has_key?('dsAttrTypeStandard:NestedGroups')
                    output['dsAttrTypeStandard:NestedGroups'].each do |generate_dscldUID|
                        results = find('GeneratedUID',generate_dscldUID)
                        if !results.empty?
                            result = results[0]
                            length_of_nested_group_name = result.index("\t") - "\t".length
                            nested_group_name = result.slice(0..length_of_nested_group_name)
                            users.concat( get_users_in_group(nested_group_name) )
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
            users.uniq
        end
```